# Implement security on messages passed from one micro service to other

Tags: microservices

I am having 4 different microservices in my application. The technology stack that I am using for the development of applications is SBT stack (Scala, Akka and Play web framework). For external clients to communicate with my micro-services, I have security mechanisms such as authorization and authentication of users using Oauth protocol, White-listing Allowable HTTP Methods and performing input validation. However, I wanted to know 2 things :

1. Is it necessary to implement security mechanisms when one microservice calls another microservice internally ?
2. If required, how to implement security on messages passed from one microservice to another ?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see three reasons :

- You'll have a better defense from the outside if all the layers implement security. It is called "defense in depth" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)).
- Other teams may contribute to your project, add their own microservices and invoke yours. You will definitely want to check their services are authorized to call yours.
- When you have a lot of microservices invoking each others, you may introduce a permission breach : you deny access to a service A to a user, but you allow him to invoke service B that invokes service A... It may be hard to detect this kind of situation. Having service A checking the permissions of the user whether it is invoked directly or not will prevent this.

To do so, your microservices should request a JWT for authentication and authorization. Each microservice checks into the JWT if the user has the required permissions to do the call. And each time a service invokes another service, it forwards the JWT, so that the other service can check the permissions at its level too.